# Java 2D graphics backgammon table (algorithm question)

Tags: java, java-2d

My problem is I need to use only one drawLine. I couldn't figure out how am I supposed to make changes at the same time in x and y while not messing with one and another. I can't use a rectangle.

```java
int x = 25;
int y = 25;

for (int i = 0; i <=8; i++) {
    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x+160, y);
    y+=20;
}

x = 25;
y = 25;

for (int i = 0; i <=8; i++) {
    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y+160);
    x+=20;
}
```

[This is what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imFFp.png)

Comment: You have to vary X and Y independently.  Use a nested `for` loop, varying X in the outer loop and varying Y in the inner loop.

Comment: There is the _[Graphics#drawPolygon](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon(int[],int[],int))_ method.

Comment: It’s a weird requirement, as the two loops are comprehensible and easy to read and that’s the most important aspect of program code. However, you can do it in a single loop, e.g. `int startX = 25, startY = 25, endX = startX + 160, endY = startY + 160; for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) { int h = i & 1, v = h ^ 1, x = startX + v * (i>>1) * 20, y = startY + h * (i>>1) * 20; g2d.drawLine(x, y, x * v + endX * h, y * h + endY * v); }` As said, I’d stick to the two loops. And well, to me, this grid doesn’t look like a backgammon board, not even remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the flowers, however, for any practical purpose, a two loops solutions stays preferable, as the single loop solution serves no other purpose than “being awesome” and solving the artificial requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holger Sama's Answer (one for):

```
    int startX = 25,
    startY = 25,
    endX = startX + 160,
    endY = startY + 160;
for (int i = 0; i <= 17; i++) {
    int h = i & 1,
        v = h ^ 1,
        x = startX + v * (i >> 1) * 20,
        y = startY + h * (i >> 1) * 20;
    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x * v + endX * h, y * h + endY * v);
}
```

My Answer (nested for):

```
    int endy = 0, endx = 160, xIncreaser  = 0, x = 25;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    int y = 25;
    x+=xIncreaser;
    if (i == 1)
        x-=20;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++){
        if (y+endy>185)
            break;
        g2d.drawLine(x,y, x+endx, y+endy);
        y+=20;
    }
    xIncreaser  = 20;
    endy = 160;
    endx = 0;
```